# Laravel Query Builder groupBy combined with relationships

Tags: sql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

Consider these 2 simple tables with a one-to-many relationship:

**cars**

- id
- brand
- user_id

**users**

- id
- username

Users can have multiple cars, every car belongs to one user.

For each car brand, I'd like to know the username who owns most of them + the amount.

Is this possible with one SQL query? I'm looking for the most elegant way to do this with Laravel Query Builder?

```
DB::table('cars')->groupBy('brand');
```

Is what I have so far...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to achieve this with a raw query? If so, you can attempt to reverse-engineer that into the various `Builder` methods. If not, that's likely a good place to start. It's a little broad at the moment.

Comment: @TimLewis no, I was not able to produce this with a raw query, that why i ask the question :)

Comment: Understandable, but like I said, that's probably the place to start. If you can generate the results you're expecting in raw SQL, then you should be able to easily reproduce that in Eloquent (`Builder`), or, if all else fails, simply do a `DB::query(DB::raw(...));` and have it execute the query that you know already works. Someone else may be able to help in the meantime, but if it's quiet, see what you can do :) Sidenote; if you've tried to generate the raw query, and had issues, post what you've tried; it might help clarify what the issue it.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you Tim, will try to do tht ;) !

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help.

```php
$sub = Car::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'cars.user_id')
->groupBy('cars.brand', 'users.id', 'users.username')
->selectRaw('users.id, 
             users.username, 
             cars.brand, 
             COUNT(cars.rand) AS brand_amount');

$count = DB::table( DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub") )
    ->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery())
    ->groupBy('brand')
    ->select('brand', 'username', DB::Raw('MAX(brand_amount) AS amount'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, this kinda works, but still not what i was looking for. I only need the user that has the most cars for that specific brand. e.g. [{
                'brand' => 'brandA',
                'amount' => 7,
                'username' => 'john'
            }
            {
                'brand' => 'brandB',
                'amount' => 8,
                'username' => 'steve'
            }] -- is that possible @TsaiKoga ?

Comment: @SebSob Yes, you can use subquery to get the max amount from records. I have changed my answer.

Comment: I get an error now: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getQuery() - any idea?

Comment: @SebSob ```getQuery()``` is the method of ```Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder```. And it works fine to me. Or you can remove the line ```->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery())```. Because you don't have the where condition.

Comment: @SebSob I have fixed this. Use Eloquent\Builder ```Car``` instead Query\Builder.

Comment: @SebSob I have already updated. And if you still want to use `DB::table('cars')`, you can just use `->mergeBindings($sub)`